# Round is returning (100, 1) instead if 100

Tags: python, function

I am trying to find the percentage of questions right but my percentage code is returning `(100, 1)` but I want it to return `100`. My code is

```py
accuracy = 100 # Setting a default.

def percentage(part, whole):
  return(round((part/whole)*100),1)
```

and the code to print is

```py
accuracy = percentage(questionsright, questionscompleted)
print("Your accuracy is now " + str(accuracy) + "% .")
```

Does anybody know why it isn't returning 100? Please Help.

Comment: Yeah, the function returns a tuple—count your parenthesis 

Comment: You are explicitly returning a tuple of  `round((part/whole)*100)` and `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have parenthesis in the wrong places in this function:

```
def percentage(part, whole):
  return(round((part/whole)*100),1)
```

Without the change, your function was returning an ordered tuple of two elements where the first element is `round((part/whole)*100)` and the second is `1`.

Here is the corrected function:

```
def percentage(part, whole):
  return round((part/whole)*100,1)
```

Comment: That was my issue. This was my first time using functions so I'm not that mad.